# Setting request geolocation Cordova

Tags: cordova, geolocation

Each time you start the application requires user permission geolocation - http://joxi.ru/KUc8VIwyTJD8bh6K_zI. It is possible to do something that would be agreed once the user and no longer show this window? Or at least change the label in the window

Comment: Use html5 local storage to set flag variable if the user is agree.Show the window if the flag is not set

Comment: This may be a consequence of the browser implementation? This questioner has the opposite problem: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16353909/814416

Answer (score 0):

I was just experiencing this problem with Cordova. Initially when I checked geolocation it just prompted the user once and then never again, but then I moved the geolocation to happen as soon as the app opens, and that's when I got the same problem you did. The problem ended up being that the geolocation was being checked before the app is fully loaded. I added a splash screen to my app to show a logo and after that when geolocation was called for the app was fully loaded and so it didn't prompt the user anymore. So basically just make sure the document is fully loaded before calling the geolocation.